# Find memory consumed by simple console C# program

Tags: c#, c++, .net, frameworks, system.diagnostics

I need to find out time and memory consumed by simple console C# program.

.Net framework has Stopwatch utility to fullfil the first task,

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        long memoryUsedInBytes = process.WorkingSet64;

        //do something            

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds + "ms elapsed.\n" + memoryUsedInBytes/1000 + " KB consumed");
```

Do we have some thing as simple as this in the framework to find memory consumed by simple console program, without using advanced diagnostic techniques.

EDIT: appending memory used code, as answered below, by Habib.

Comment: @NahumLitvin: That gives a number which may or may not represent "memory consumed" depending on your definition of memory use.

Comment: This doesn't measure the time consumed, but the time elapsed. If another higher-priority process runs at the same time (and insufficient cores are available) the Stopwatch will still run but your program won't. See the Perf. Counter answer, that also can measure time consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get the current [process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) and then using the property [WorkingSet64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx) you can get the size in bytes.

[Process.WorkingSet64 Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx)

> Gets the amount of physical memory allocated for the associated
>   process.

also

> This property can be used to monitor memory usage on computers with
>   32-bit processors or 64-bit processors. The property value is
>   equivalent to the Working Set performance counter for the process.

```
Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long memoryUsedInBytes = process.WorkingSet64;
```

Comment: using Process.GetCurrentProcess() & GC.GetTotalMemory() gives different values at any particular line of code. And GetTotalMemory always returns less value.

Comment: for a sample run Process.GetCurrentProcess() returned 8.3MB while GC.GetTotalMemory()  returned 365KB.

Comment: Does this mean that amount of physical memory allocated for a process includes more item when compared with total memory allocated by managed code at particular time ?

Comment: @autrevo, yes that is correct, also [`Gc.GetTotalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) returns **best approximation of number of bytes currently allocated in the managed memory**

Answer (score 2):

.NET processes expose a rather rich set of Performance Counters. You can use Windows' Performance Monitor to add the counters to a graph, either general memory counters (bytes allocated and such) or .NET-specific counters, like bytes in each GC generation and the like:

[image]

Comment: Having difficulty in locating  .NET CLR memory counter on win xp. Performance counters definitely offers detailed graphical analysis for large application, for simple application it seems more time consuming :-) +1

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the Garbage Collector can help you

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/8bfa495b-bed2-40fd-adbd-cb998b74af32

```
GC.GetTotalMemory()
```

Comment: As per the hyperlink posted above, "In particular, GC.GetTotalMemory() will give you the total memory allocation by managed code at a specific time." +1 for this

Comment: Simon, using Process.GetCurrentProcess() & GC.GetTotalMemory() gives different values at any particular line of code. And GetTotalMemory always returns less value.   for a sample run Process.GetCurrentProcess() returned 8.3MB while GC.GetTotalMemory() returned 365KB.   Does this mean that amount of physical memory allocated for a process includes more item when compared with total memory allocated by managed code at particular time ?